# How to create a new calculated column in Excel - Getting data from SSAS model into an excel tabular form

Tags: excel, ssas, olap-cube, tabular-form

We are loading data from an SSAS model into an excel tabular form and we are trying to put information in a second column depending on the first one, In this case we have 2 fields coming from the SSAS: Amendment Amount and Record Date, we are trying to change the column Record Date depending on the information coming from Amendment date. It means, if Amendment amount comes empty from SSAS we have to put blank spaces in the column Record Date. In contrast, if some data comes in the amendment amount field we need to put the information coming from Record Date field
It could be explained as a formula as well as follow:

IF(PO[Amendment Amount] >0,PO[Record Date] )

Question about amendment date:

1. What is the best way for doing this kind of calculations? Notice that data is coming from SSAS into Excel tabular form
2. Is there some conditional formatting available to apply in this case?

Example: Is displaying information in Record Date column when we don't have amendment amount, it is wrong:

```
po_number   |  Record_date   | Amendment_amount
A1          |  2019-05-03    |                
A2          |  2019-05-25    | 4350
A3          |  2019-04-30    |       
a4          |  2019-04 08    | 2100
```

We are looking for something like this: (if we have Total amendment Amount we show up Record date, else we show up blank spaces)

results expected:

```
po_number   |  Record_date   | Amendment_amount
A1          |                |                
A2          |  2019-05-25    | 4350
A3          |                |       
a4          |  2019-04 08    | 2100
```

Note : We do not want to do changes to the model (visual studio), we want to do changes on Excel, specifically on each Excel report as needed.

One more thing : Amendment_Amount is a measure field coming from the model(visual studio)

I tried to use a MDX calculated measure (OLAP tools) as follow, but it doesn't worked:

```
IIF(
(
  Not(IsEmpty([Measures].[Amendment Amount]))
  AND  [Measures].[Amendment Amount] >0
),
[PO].[Record Date],
1
)
```

Some idea to solve it please?

Answer (score 0):

think about using excel cube functions:

cubevalue and cubemember